# Regarding when the Talmud refers to "Yeshu", is it an anacronism and an urban myth, when some say that's an acronym for Ymach Shmoh VeZichroh?

Tags: talmud-gemara

Regarding when the Talmud refers to "Yeshu", is it an anacronism and an urban myth, when some say that's an acronym for Ymach Shmoh VeZichroh?

For example, I read once that in the Syrian dialect of Aramaic, the name Yehoshua has a short form of Yeshua and Yeshu. And in that Syrian dialect of Aramaic, Yeshua and Yeshu are spelt with an Ayin.  Yud Shin Waw Ayin. Whereas in Hebrew, to put the Aramaic name Yeshu into Hebrew, one would have to drop the Ayin at the end, which the Talmud does.  I read that the curse Ymach Shmoh VeZichroh doesn't date as far back as the Talmud, and so anybody that thinks that the authors of the Talmud had that acronym in mind, is incorrect and is applying the acronym retroactively.

Comment: related thing I read https://www.quora.com/Is-Yeshu-Yeshua-a-derogatory-Hebrew-name-for-Jesus/answer/Andrej-Friedemann/

Comment: Note that Yeshu HaNotzri isn't necessarily Oso HaIsh, the latter of which is more likely to be the intent of "Yemash shemo vezichro". See Tosafos HaRosh to Sotah (where Yeshu HaNotzri appears)

Comment: @robev well referring to somebody as  Oto HaIsh "that man" is a lot different to saying "May his name and memory be obliterated"!!  I wonder if the "may his name and memory be obliterated" only goes as far as yiddish, since it's such an extreme exaggerated thing, nothing like the mild "oto haish"!

Comment: The acronym you are referencing comes from Sefer Toldot Yeshu HaNotzri which is a compilation of portions of Talmud and elsewhere which were censored heavily when Christians came to power in Europe. According to the account there, this title was one of the judgements of the Beit Din that tried his case. His true name was to be concealed and he was only to be known by the acronym.